# Including &bucket=terms is causing error / incomplete response

Tags: echonest

This only started happening today, but if I include the "&bucket=terms" in a request, it leaves out all of the other details.

No terms - contains all other information
http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/search?api_key=__&format=json&name=brand%20new&results=1&bucket=familiarity&bucket=familiarity&bucket=hotttnesss&bucket=id:spotify&bucket=artist_location&bucket=years_active

Has terms - only returns id and name
http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/search?api_key=__&format=json&name=brand%20new&results=1&bucket=familiarity&bucket=familiarity&bucket=hotttnesss&bucket=id:spotify&bucket=artist_location&bucket=years_active&bucket=terms

Answer (score 0):

These two are not working either. I noticed it this weekend. I didn't find any info about 'disabling' moods or styles in their API.

http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/list_terms?api_key=API_KEY&format=json&type=mood

http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/list_terms?api_key=API_KEY&format=json&type=style

Comment: Interesting, I've tried reaching out for support but haven't had much luck. Just saw this today though and wanted to share in case you didn't see the announcement: http://developer.echonest.com/